# Stop long running scheduled job

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, jobs, scheduled-tasks

I need to launch a scheduled job at 12 o'clock at night and keep this job running for a period of 8 hours. What happens now is that the job is running for more than 12 hours and I really need to avoid running for so long. I have used the `Max Run Duration` option but it does not have the desired effect for my purpose. I would appreciate if someone could give me an example of how it should be. Database is Oracle 12c. Here I put the script:

```
BEGIN
  SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB
    (
       job_name        => 'SYS.POB_TB_JOB'
      ,start_date      => TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2019/02/10 00:05:00.000000 America/New_York','yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss.ff tzr')
      ,repeat_interval => 'FREQ=DAILY;BYDAY=MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI,SAT,SUN'
      ,end_date        => NULL
      ,job_class       => 'DEFAULT_JOB_CLASS'
      ,job_type        => 'STORED_PROCEDURE'
      ,job_action      => 'SELLER.FILL_TB_S1'
      ,comments        => NULL
    );

  SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE
    ( name      => 'SYS.POB_TB_JOB'
     ,attribute => 'MAX_RUN_DURATION'
     ,value     => TO_DSINTERVAL('+000 05:00:00'));

  SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE
    ( name      => 'SYS.POB_TB_JOB'
     ,attribute => 'number_of_arguments'
     ,value     => 4);

  SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_JOB_ARGUMENT_VALUE
    ( job_name             => 'SYS.POB_TB_JOB'
     ,argument_position    => 1
     ,argument_value       => '30');

  SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_JOB_ARGUMENT_VALUE
    ( job_name             => 'SYS.POB_TB_JOB'
     ,argument_position    => 2
     ,argument_value       => 'N');

  SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_JOB_ARGUMENT_VALUE
    ( job_name             => 'SYS.POB_TB_JOB'
     ,argument_position    => 3
     ,argument_value       => 'N');

  SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_JOB_ARGUMENT_VALUE
    ( job_name             => 'SYS.POB_TB_JOB'
     ,argument_position    => 4
     ,argument_value       => '1');

  SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.ENABLE
    (name                  => 'SYS.POB_TB_JOB');
END;
/
```

Answer (score 3):

Attribute `MAX_RUN_DURATION` does not terminate the job, it only raises an event.

I created a procedure like this:

```
procedure SchedulerWatchdog(jobName in varchar2) is

cursor Jobs is
select job_name
from user_scheduler_jobs
where JOB_NAME = jobName
   AND STATE = 'RUNNING'
   AND systimestamp - LAST_START_DATE > MAX_RUN_DURATION;

begin
   for aJob in Jobs loop
      DBMS_SCHEDULER.STOP_JOB(JobName, FORCE => TRUE);
   end loop;
end;
```

Run this procedure by scheduler job, perhaps every Minute.

Answer (score 0):

Context:

If what you need is for the job to continue running until 8 hours have passed since 12 p.m., this is the way to tell the job to perform a pause type until 8 a.m.

```
PROCEDURE SELLER.FILL_TB_S1 IS
BEGIN
   /* YOUR CODE */
   WHILE TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH24MI') != 800 LOOP NULL; END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: I think such a loop will heat up your CPU. Instead of `NULL;` use better `DBMS_LOCK.SLEEP(60);` or similar.